# understanding dataclass field usage

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, python-dataclasses

I am confused about how the usage of field() in dataclasses works.
I have this (senseless) example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str = field(init=False)

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)


dieter = Person()
dieter.print_name()
```

I would expect this to create an empty string. However, this only happens, when I add the parameter default="".
Evenmore, in pycharm, no syntax highlight complains, when I write following code:

```
name: int = field(init=False, default="")
```

What is the point of type hints, if there is not syntax highlighting?
I don't really have any problem, I'm just trying to grasp, what is actually happening.

The usage case is, that I am creating a class, that later contains matplotlib axes, plots etc. Since they don't exist in the beginning, I only want to initialize them, so they are connected to the class, and can later be created.

Comment: If you just used `name = field(init=False)`, `dataclass` would ignore `name` altogether and it would just be an ordinary class attribute.

Comment: Remember, the class is defined first, then passed to `dataclass`.  The decorator uses the `__annotation__` attribute of the class to see which names have type hints at all.

Comment: Mypy correctly identifies the issue and the Mypy PyCharm plugin highlights the error too if you want to get better type checking in your IDE. Not that it explains why the built-in type checker doesn't detect it

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The `dataclass()` decorator examines the class to find `field`s. A `field` is defined as **a class variable that has a type annotation**. With two exceptions described below, **nothing in `dataclass()` examines the type specified in the variable annotation**.

So the type hint is mainly used as a flag to tell `dataclass` to pay attention to the name.

The two exceptions are if the annotation is `ClassVar` or `InitVar`, used to indicate that the name is not an instance attribute, but either a class attribute or an init-only parameter, respectively.

What I consider a third exception is the new `KW_ONLY` value introduced in Python 3.10, which indicates that the following fields cannot be passed as positional arguments to `__init__`. (The "field" so annotated doesn't define a field at all, but it's still a decorated name whose type `dataclass` pays attention to.)